# How do I get to Configuration Properties menu in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2012, configurationproperty

I have searched and search, and cannot find this menu for the life of me. If anyone knows where to go to get there, please let me know...

This is an article on what I am trying to do 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/16/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog shown in the article is part of the standard project property pages for C++ projects. It should appear when you right-click on a C++ project and select properties.